# how to texture of images?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

I am using too many fruits and vegetables images in iphone game, so how can I make texture of such images, because as per I read that every image in texture in OpenGL ES, so what should I do?

I have developed 6 iOS application, but this is my first game, so please guide me in proper way so that I can get idea.

Comment: what do you mean too many, is it taking too much memory, [UIImage imageNamed:] will take care to not reallocate memory for exiting images in your bundle.

Comment: @Grady, I am using different types of images at same time, means these images will move from down side to upside in iphone, and user will drag and drop images at particular box, you got my idea?

Comment: So I still don't get the question. If you're asking how to do texturing in OpenGL ES, I suggest you first read how OpenGL works at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `glTexImage2D` to upload raw pixel data to OpenGL in order to populate a texture. You can use Core Graphics and particularly `CGBitmapContextCreate` to get the raw pixel data to get the raw pixel data of (or convert to raw pixel data) anything else Core Graphics can draw — which for you probably means a CGImageRef, either through a C API load of a PNG or JPG, or just using the result of `[someUIImage CGImage]`.

Apple's [GLSprite](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GLSprite/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007325) sample (you'll need to be logged in, and I'm not sure those links work externally, but do a search in the Developer Library if necessary) is probably a good starting point. I'm not 100% behind the class structure, but if you look into EAGLView.m, lines 272 to 305, the code there loads a PNG from disk then does the necessary steps to post it off to OpenGL, with a decent amount of commenting.